# Excel, How many same types a repeating name has

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge list of different car names which are repeating and their types. I need to sum the amout of types each car has. For example Name1 has 2 van and one medium, Name2 has 2 van 1 medium, Name3 has 1 non_cargo and 2 medium and so on.
I don't know how to make a formula for that.
I have uploaded example screenshot.
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: COUNTIF or COUNTIFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without no excel version constraint you can use the following assuming your names are in the range `A2:A10` for example:

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A10), COUNTIF(A2:A10,UNIQUE(A2:A10)))
```

It returns in the first column the unique names and the second column the corresponding counts for each unique names.

If you want to have a count by **name** and **type** better to use a *Pivot Table* like this:

[image: sample Pivot Table]

Comment: Thank you, coudln't understand =HSTACK, but Pivot Table worked for me!

Comment: thanks, check the documentation for [HSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2) and availability in your excel version.

Answer (score 1):

When using Office 365 you could use:

```
=LET(data,A1:B12,
          _d1,INDEX(data,,1),
          _d2,INDEX(data,,2),
     u,UNIQUE(data),
          _u1,INDEX(u,,1),
          _u2,INDEX(u,,2),
     m,MMULT(
             (TRANSPOSE(_d1)=_u1)* 
             (TRANSPOSE(_d2)=_u2),
             SEQUENCE(COUNTA(_d1),,1,0)
             ),
HSTACK(u,m))
```

[image]

In older Excel you can use the following:

In `D2` use: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$12,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS($D$1:$D1,$A$1:$A$12,$E$1:$E1,$B$1:$B$12),0)),"")` drag from `D2` to `E12` (or up to when you see empty values).

In `F2` use `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,$D2,$B$1:$B$12,$E2)` and drag down.

[image]

Comment: Good idea, to take into account as an alternative to Pivot Table. I am wondering if it is possible to return the information in a similar form as in the pivot table?, i.e. the types by columns so there is no need to repeat the same name on each row. Thanks

Comment: @David Leal Check this out: `=LET(data,A1:B12,_d1,INDEX(data,,1),_d2,INDEX(data,,2),_u1,UNIQUE(_d1),_u2,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(_d2)),m,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(_d1&_d2)=TOCOL(_u1&_u2)),ROW(_d1)^0),x,INDEX(m,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(_u1),COUNTA(_u2))),VSTACK(HSTACK("name",_u2),HSTACK(_u1,x)))` https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGGfs.jpg